# Set display settings for another user in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 20.10 on a laptop and I have the close lid setting to ignore so I can close it and it still works on my external monitor.  I have added a new user,  but when I log in as the new user,  these setting apparently do not transfer over. When I login as the new user, I get a blank screen(s) Is there a way to

a) when I first boot up,  use the dual monitor settings,  and

b) I have the laptop tucked away nicely in a rack with a lot of things hooked up to it and I don't want to have to take it out every time I add a user.  How do I set a users display settings from the terminal?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. You can get help on one of our sister sites, such as [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `xrand` is the CLI utility to control everything about 'monitors' and 'displays'. The main issue is that it needs connection to specific X server (the one, handling monitors).

Generally, you may try to use

```
export DISPLAY=:0
XAUTHORITY=/home/amarao/.Xauthority
```

After that you can try to use `xranr` to control your monitor.

But I found that xrandr is really piky on the current monitor state (f.e. it does not work if you switch to Linux pty).